# setting an atttribute in rails console - transaction rolled back

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I've used this forum gem before and also been able to set the forem_admin to "true" using the console. However, this time it's rolling back the transaction when I try to save.

You can see below that I set the forem_admin to "true," saved it, it rolled back the transaction (which means it didn't save), I did "u" and it showed forem_admin = true but when I restarted the console it showed forem_admin = false.

If anyone's familiar with this gem, I think this forem_state attribute is new, so I'm wondering if anything's changed.

I'm not an SQL pro but one thing that looks funny to me is the line

```
"users"."id" != 5
```

I would have expected it to have been `"users"."id" = 5` i.e. with no "!", because the id of the user "signuplinks" is 5.

this is a rails 3.2 app

**update** when I do `u.errors` after u.save, I'm getting this error message

```
@messages={:password=>["can't be blank"]}
```

**Console**

```
   ruby-1.9.3-rc1 :001 > u = User.last
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 5, email: "myemail@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$axjwcO.kU4/mqC9Llyj.b.r/2jJULnWKmG7Pi3Zu1AE3...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2012-03-05 03:37:59", last_sign_in_at: "2012-03-05 03:37:59", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2012-03-05 03:37:58", confirmation_sent_at: "2012-03-05 03:34:33", unconfirmed_email: nil, created_at: "2012-03-05 03:34:33", updated_at: "2012-03-05 03:37:59", name: "signuplinks", country: "Canada", image: "3.png", forem_admin: false, forem_state: "pending_review"> 
ruby-1.9.3-rc1 :002 > u.forem_admin = true
 => true 
ruby-1.9.3-rc1 :003 > u.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."name") = LOWER('signuplinks') AND "users"."id" != 5) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('signuplinks@gmail.com') AND "users"."id" != 5) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => false 
ruby-1.9.3-rc1 :004 > u
 => #<User id: 5, email: "myemail@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$axjwcO.kU4/mqC9Llyj.b.r/2jJULnWKmG7Pi3Zu1AE3...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2012-03-05 03:37:59", last_sign_in_at: "2012-03-05 03:37:59", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2012-03-05 03:37:58", confirmation_sent_at: "2012-03-05 03:34:33", unconfirmed_email: nil, created_at: "2012-03-05 03:34:33", updated_at: "2012-03-05 03:37:59", name: "signuplinks", country: "Canada", image: "3.png", forem_admin: true, forem_state: "pending_review"> 
ruby-1.9.3-rc1 :005 > exit
Michael-Pro:ic michl$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.1)
ruby-1.9.3-rc1 :001 > u = User.last
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 5, email: "myemail@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$axjwcO.kU4/mqC9Llyj.b.r/2jJULnWKmG7Pi3Zu1AE3...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2012-03-05 03:37:59", last_sign_in_at: "2012-03-05 03:37:59", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2012-03-05 03:37:58", confirmation_sent_at: "2012-03-05 03:34:33", unconfirmed_email: nil, created_at: "2012-03-05 03:34:33", updated_at: "2012-03-05 03:37:59", name: "signuplinks", country: "Canada", image: "3.png", forem_admin: false, forem_state: "pending_review">
```

Comment: What is the name of the gem? It looks like there might be a validation step that is failing on the User model. After trying to save, do `u.errors` and post that output.

Comment: Presumably `u.id` is 5 so those WHEREs are looking for people that have a name/email of "signuplinks" and are not `u` (i.e. `id != 5`); so those are name and email uniqueness checks and part of the validation process. What are the side effects of `u.forem_admin = true`? Is it changing the email address or name behind the scenes? Is there only one admin allowed? Anything else interesting about admins?

Comment: @wpgreenway updated OP. there is a password blank error message. don't know why.

Comment: @muistooshort the id of user "signuplinks" is 5. why would it look for people whose name is "signuplinks" and whose id is not 5. Is that part of the uniqueness validator? seems backwards. There's no limit on forem admins, and u.forem_admin doesn't appear to be changing anything.

Comment: If `name = 'signuplinks' and id != 5` matches anything then you have a duplicate `name` as only `5` is supposed to have that name. What does your model look like? That will probably explain the "can't be blank" error you're seeing.

Comment: @muistooshort you were right. i had included password in the validates presence of validator

Answer (score 2):

actually, this was my own fault. Thanks to @muistooshort for pointing out problem probably is in model. I had included "password" in the validates_presence of validator which was stopping me from changing user details in the console (without including password)